# how to add action buttons in android app

Tags: android

i m having problem in action buttons for my app. i did as per the tutorial from http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html but i get a red underlined error telling there is no file action_search in R.id and no methods openSearch() and openSettings() i fixed this by manually creating the methods and the action_search file and the app run on my device but the search button doesnot works and i now i cannot delete the action_search from R.id plz help

Comment: Try adding the code that is giving you trouble.

Comment: this is a portion of code for my mainactivity.java file i fixed the
action_search by modifying R.java and now i cannot restore my original R.java file
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
                openSearch();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                openSettings();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running a clean on your build? Whenever you have issues with R. related things try to clean so the resources get rebuilt. This can sometimes be caused by copy and pasting chunks of code around...